# background size 100% changing aspect ratio if needed?

Tags: css

Is it possible to set a background image to be 100% of the height and 100% of a div? So if the div's aspect ratio changes then the image aspect ration changes too.

This doesn't work:

```
  background-size: 100% 100%;
```

This cuts of the image rather than changing its aspect ratio:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Comment: Please post the HTML of the elements in the layout you are building.  Your question needs some clarification.  You say: "100% of the height and 100% of a div" what does the 2nd 100% refer to?

Comment: Sorry, but the answer ("yes") is really easy to find with Google.

Comment: @MrLister I think the answer is actually "no" https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: @jdln I don't see the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/ktgep8bq/1/

Comment: @jdln Wait, I realise now I should have asked what browser you want this to run on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`background-size: 100% 100%;` does fill the whole area (possibly changing the image's aspect ratio).

Note that `background-size` is placed *after* `background` definition.

See snippet:

```css
.bgimage
{
  width: 100%; height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/Drazet%2C_a_black_feral_cat.jpg) no-repeat center center;

  background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bgimage">
  ...
</div>
```

Image source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_cat#/media/File:Drazet,_a_black_feral_cat.jpg
Author: [Ordog](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Ordog~commonswiki)

Comment: This cuts the image off. I need the full image to be shown.

Comment: @jdln, I misunderstood your question first. Updated the answer.